# Joining Linq tables using classes C# WPF Linq

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, class, datagrid

I need to join these two tables ( **tblProjects** & **tblEmployeeLoginDetails** ) using these two public classes that I have created( **PDData** & **EIDData** )

Here is my Join coding where I fill my datagrid:

```
    private void FillProjectsDataGrid()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
           var Join = (from a in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                        join b in DC.tblProjects
                        on a.LoginID equals b.ProjectID
                        where b.ProjectID != null
                        select new 
                        { 
                            b.ProjectID, 
                            b.ProjectName, 
                            b.ProjectStatus, 

                            a.EmployeeName, 
                            a.EmployeeSurname
                        }).ToList();

           dgViewProjects.ItemsSource = Join;
        }
    }
```

The join works and I can fill my datagrid, but I need to equal the values from the two tables to the two classes that I have created.

> Example: EIDData.Name = a.EmployeeName

My classes coding: **PDData**:

```
public struct PDData
{
    public string _project;

    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Class **EIDData**:

```
public struct EIDData
{
    public string _sts;

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string IDNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string HomeAddress { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Province { get; set; }
    public Binary SetImage { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea how to do this.
I want to use the classes with the join, because it is going to be easier to manage all my data in my datagrid's selection changed event.

Anyone with an idea or advice would be appreciated! Thank you.

EDIT: here is my selection changed event for my datagrid in case anyone needs it.

```
    private void dgViewProjects_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext DC = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            tblProject tblP = new tblProject();
            lblProjectName.Content = tblP.ProjectName.ToString();                
        }
    }
```

I then get this error once I click on a row:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
>   occurred in Haze.exe
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a dictionary

```css
                var dict = (from a in DC.tblEmployeeLoginDetails
                            join b in DC.tblProjects
                            on a.UserID equals b.ProjectID
                            select new {key = a.UserID, value = new {employee = a, project = b}})
                            .ToDictionary(x => x.key, y => y.value) ;
```